# Badge push increment only works in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Badge push increment only works when my device runs in xcode, but when I unplug it only  recieve push notification with sound, alert correctly, but increment badge not appears in app icon.
Anyone know about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show how you set this up and increment it in code?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, and this is my php script wich runs with my terminal osx.

```
$deviceToken = '3d51...';
$tokenIpad   = '3bf2a..';


// Put your private key's passphrase here: // Second pass wich has been created
$passphrase = '37...';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Hello!';
$badge   = '1';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body = array(
    'aps' => array(
        "content-available" => "1",
        "alert"             => $message,
        "badge"             => $badge,
        "sound"             => 'default'
    )   
 );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Add device tokens
$tokens = array(
    $deviceToken,
    //$tokenIpad  
);

foreach ($tokens as $value) 
{
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $value) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) .                $payload; 
  $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
}

 // Close the connection to the server
  fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code in the AppDelegate:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

{
    NSLog(@"Test %@", userInfo);

```
if (userInfo)
{
    if ([userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]) {
        if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"]) {

            NSInteger increment = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badge"] intValue];
            increment = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber + increment;
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = increment;
        }
    }
}
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
```

}
Thanks again.